# How do I instruct WinDBG to only load source files for certain modules?

Tags: .net, windbg

I've added a source path to WinDBG, and now when I attach to my .NET process WinDBG takes a very long time to load modules.  Is there a way to tell WinDBG to only load/associate source files for a subset of modules?  I only care about source from my own code.

Comment: It shouldn't be slow but for the first time, that's when it tries to download .pdb files from the symbol server.  Document how you setup the symbol server cache.

Comment: This isn't a problem with the symbol cache.  Everything was fast until I added source path.  Here's the setup: SRV*c:\symbols*\\machine1\ProductSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Comment: I'm caching symbols to c:\symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure deferred symbol load is enabled (.symopt +0x4).
2. Try using only qualified symbols (i.e.   module!name) and modify  the Resolve Unqualified Symbols option on the Debug menu.
3. Try to get to find why symbol loading takes a long time.  Use "!sym noisy".  If symbols are being loaded from a remote network location try using cache*c:\some\path\to\cache

Answer (score 0):

- I keep my sympath empty except for my own code unless I need it. I have an alias in ntsdi.ini to add the windows etc. symbols. This speeds up load times a lot.
- I'll second the deferred loading